# Hide scrollbar and add arrows instead

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a "div" with some images and there is a scrollbar at the bottom.
What I would like to do is adding arrows to scroll and make the scrollbar invisible

So far I have tried some of my methods but it did not work.

```css
.scoll-pane {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="scoll-pane mt-4">
              <ul class="photos">
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide the scroll bar with `webkit-scrollbar` and `scrollbar-width` CSS. Additionally, you can use some simple javascript selectors to "slide" a div when buttons are pressed, as demonstrated in the example below:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('slide');
button.onclick = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    sideScroll(container,'right',25,100,10);
};

var back = document.getElementById('slideBack');
back.onclick = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    sideScroll(container,'left',25,100,10);
};

function sideScroll(element,direction,speed,distance,step){
    scrollAmount = 0;
    var slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
        if(direction == 'left'){
            element.scrollLeft -= step;
        } else {
            element.scrollLeft += step;
        }
        scrollAmount += step;
        if(scrollAmount >= distance){
            window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
        }
    }, speed);
}
```

```css
.scoll-pane {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    -ms-overflow-style: scroll;  // IE 10+
    scrollbar-width: none;  // Firefox
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
}

  .scoll-pane::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none;  // Safari and Chrome
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="scoll-pane mt-4" id="container">
              <ul class="photos">
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<button id="slideBack" type="button">Prev</button>
<button id="slide" type="button">Next</button>
 
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you are looking for is a Carousel?

```html
<style>
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff0000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff0000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;

}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/test" alt="...">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/test" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/test"  alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/test"  alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like this, it is very simple code.

```
 /* SIDE SCROLL PARTIAL*/

var frameWidth = $('.products__wrapper').width(), // width of div showed on display
    scrollElmtWidth = $('.products__wrapper')[0].scrollWidth, // width of div also with hidden part
    scrollAmount = 0,
    distance = 0,
    maxDistance = scrollElmtWidth - frameWidth; // width of hidden part - width which must be uncovered bz scrolling
    scrollStep = maxDistance/4; // divide all resolution to 4 steps
    

$('.right-arrow-partial').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    distance = $('.products__wrapper').scrollLeft();        
        
    if (distance < maxDistance) {   
    //if scrolled distance is less then max distance + 1/4 px each time -> after max distance have not to count + 1/4 px

        scrollAmount += scrollStep;

        $('.products__wrapper').animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 500);
    }   
})

$('.left-arrow-partial').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    distance = $('.products__wrapper').scrollLeft();

    //if (scrollAmount > maxDistance) {scrollAmount = maxDistance}
    
    if (scrollAmount > 0) {     
    // if it is start of scroll area -> cannot discount - 1/4 px 
        scrollAmount -= scrollStep; 

        $('.products__wrapper').animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 500);                   
    }
})
```